# $U(p^m)\bigoplus U(q^n)$ is not cyclic if $p$ and $q$ are odd primes and $m$ and $n$ are positive integers.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$U(p^m)\bigoplus U(q^n)$ is not cyclic if $p$ and $q$ are odd primes and $m$ and $n$ are positive integers.

Here is what i got so far,
 $U$ is multipication modulo group and $\bigoplus$ is external direct product.
Here is my attempt so far, 
Number of elements in $U(p^m)$ is given by $\phi(p^m)$ where $\phi$ is euler totient fuction. 
$$
\phi(p^m) = p^m ( 1 - 1/p) = p^k(p-1)         
$$
which is an even number. Similarly  $\phi(q^n)$ is even number. So, $gcd(|p^m|,|q^n|)\neq1$. This implies that $lcm(|p^m|,|q^n|)\neq|p^m||q^n|$.
Therefore $U(p^m)\bigoplus U(q^n)$ is not cyclic.

If this is not legit, I would appreciate hints instead of answers since this is a homework question.

Comment: Sure, this is fine. Notice that $U(p^m) \oplus U(q^n)$ contains a noncyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/(2) \oplus \mathbb{Z}/(2)$, so it can't be cyclic. (Is this saying too much?)

Comment: @user43208 thats a great insight, I would have been able to come up with it myself. I was curious if by 'Sure, this is fine' did you mean my proof is also fine?

Comment: Yes, what I meant is that you were probably on the right track. This is off the top of my head, so it might not be the most efficient argument, but a finite abelian group $A$ is cyclic only if its exponent (the least $n > 0$ such that $a^n = 1$ for all $n$) equals the order of $A$. Here the exponent is the lcm, whereas the order is the product; since they disagree, the group is not cyclic.

Comment: @user43208 oops sorry, I meant I woulnd't have been able to comeup with that on my own in my previous comment. Thanks for your help that was very helpful.